# Manage object movement by keyboard

Tags: java, multithreading, game-physics, keylistener

I'm a beginner in Java and I'm trying to make a simple video game.
At the moment I make sure that a ball moves alone into the panel with a Thread .
The problem that I would to resolve is to change the direction of the ball by keyboard. 
I tried to implement KeyListener or  extend  KeyAdapter but I don't know why it doesn't work...
I post my code without keyListener or Adapter and I really appreciate if someone can tell me how I can manage these movements.

```
package threadball;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ThreadBall extends JPanel {


  int xDirection, yDirection;

  private Rectangle ball;
  private BallThread ballThread;

  private class BallThread implements Runnable {

      private int sleep = 5;
      private Thread thread;

      @Override
      public void run() {
          try {
              while (true) {
                  moveBall();
                  repaint();
                  Thread.sleep(sleep);
              }
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          }
      }

      public void start() {
          stop();
          thread = new Thread(this);
          thread.start();
      }

      public void stop() {
          if (thread != null && thread.isAlive()) {
              thread.interrupt();
          }
      }
  }

  public ThreadBall() {

      this.setBackground(Color.white);
      this.xDirection = 1;
      this.yDirection = 1;
      this.ball = new Rectangle(20, 20);
      ball.x = 150;
      ball.y = 0;

      this.ballThread = new BallThread();
      this.ballThread.start();
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.fillOval(this.ball.x, this.ball.y, this.ball.width, this.ball.height);
  }

  public void moveBall() {
      this.ball.x += this.xDirection;
      this.ball.y += this.yDirection;

      if (this.ball.x <= 0) {
          this.xDirection = 1;
      } else if (this.ball.x >= this.getWidth()) {
          this.xDirection = -1;
      }

      if (this.ball.y <= 0) {
          this.yDirection = 1;
      } else if (this.ball.y >= this.getHeight()) {
          this.yDirection = -1;
      }
   }
}
```

P.s. The '1' in xDirection and in yDirection means that the x moves towards right of 1 pixel and the y towards down. -1 -> x towards left of 1 pixel and y towards up.

My problem is that I tried to do something like that:

```
    private class keyListenerTest extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            xDirection = -1;
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            xDirection = 1;
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            yDirection = -1;
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            yDirection = 1;
        }
      }
   }
```

in "public class ThreadBall" and I tryied to add "keyListenerTest in ThreadBall's constructor with
    addKeyListener(new keyListenerTest());

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved...I have to pass a parameter MainFrame pFrame in threadBall's constructor and then add the keyListener to pFrame.
Thus

```
public ThreadBall(MainFrame pFrame) {

  pFrame.addKeyListener(new keyListener());
  this.setBackground(Color.white);
  this.xDirection = 1;
  this.yDirection = 1;
  this.ball = new Rectangle(20, 20);
  ball.x = 150;
  ball.y = 0;

  this.ballThread = new BallThread();
  this.ballThread.start();
```

}

and in the main Frame I added a new ThreadBall a passed "this"(the frame) to it.

```
   public MainFrame() {
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.add(new ThreadBall(this));
}
```

I hope this solution could help someone who had my same problem ;) .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use KeyEventDispatcher it will listen to all key presses and report them to you:

```
public static void loadKeyboardManager(){
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher(){

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            //TODO your code                
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this helps :).